# How do I disable requirement to enter password after I close and reopen the lid?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, password, macbook-pro

I don't like having to re-enter my password if I've just closed the lid for only 5 - 10 minutes.  How can I disable this?  I've already tried going to System Preferences --> Security & Privacy, and setting it to require a password only 1 hour after sleep or screensaver.

Mid-2014 Macbook Pro running Mavericks v10.9.4

Comment: Would you please edit your question to include the specify laptop model and the version of Mac OS X which is currently loaded? This will enable responders to give you a more concise and meaningful answer.

Comment: So System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login options > Automatic Login is active?

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, "lid closed" is an entirely different event than "sleep or screen saver" and you cannot disable asking for a password when the laptop is opened. There is a brief timeout where you can reopen the lid, in some cases, but it's only a few seconds.